# Detect status of an input caret under any or most Linux DE's?

Tags: linux, bash, keyboard, keyboard-events, dbus

So I have come up with this solution for Gnome 3 w/ ibus, but I need something that also works under KDE and XFCE or not be DE dependent at all. I just need to know if a text field is currently waiting for input and this is the solution that currently works under Ubuntu 19.10.

I just need to make it more cross compatible with other DE's.

```
IBUSADD=$(cat ~/.config/ibus/bus/`ls ~/.config/ibus/bus -1rt | tail -n1` | awk -F'IBUS_ADDRESS=' '{print $2}' | xargs)

dbus-monitor --address $IBUSADD "path='/org/freedesktop/IBus/Panel/Extension/Emoji',interface='org.freedesktop.IBus.Panel',member='FocusOut'"
```

If ibus needs to be installed then this is what I install, but under GalliumOS (xfce) I still don't have access to the org.freedesktop.ibus.panel location. I need to find another way.

```
# Actually ibus-mozc ibus-anthy installs japanese support - 
# may not need to do that just to run ibus-setup.. 
# unless it brings in missing dependencies for ibus-setup?
sudo apt-get install ibus-mozc ibus-anthy
ibus-setup
```

I'd also be more than happy to see any solutions written in C, but a bash or scripting language solution will work just fine as that is what I currently have.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure I just found an answer that resolved this more or less. Alternatives will be appreciated, but I now realized that the other system I installed ibus on just needed to have its keyboard input moved to use ibus via the drop down menu.[image]

The command to enable it as found elsewhere, would like to query it too, but can't seem to find a get command.

```
im-config -n ibus
```

Additionally the above solution actually works if the filter is less specific. Removing any mention of the Emoji extension, which may or may not be enabled is sufficient and the solution then compatible with any DE that works with IBus from what I can tell.

```
path='/org/freedesktop/IBus/Panel
```